# How to cache only font files and access them from cache

Tags: javascript, caching, promise, content-type

i'm trying to figure out how to use a Promise for caching font files with the `content-type` `font/woff`& `font/woff2`.
I want to pass in an url of a website as argument and the Promise fetches all files matching the defined `content-type` and put them into the `Cache`.
After that, i want to access the cached font files from the `Cache`.

Could anyone please help me to figure out the right way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "*the `Cache`*"? Which cache are you talking about? Why would you need promises for it?

Comment: I mean the Cache functionality like it's implemented in ServiceWorkers (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Cache)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`service-worker`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/):

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(caches.open('your-cache-name').then((cache) => {
  console.log('installing service worker', event);
  return cache.addAll([
    'paths/to/your/font/files',
   ]);
 }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
  if (response) {
    return response;
  }
  return fetch(event.request);
 }).catch(err => console.log('nope not in the cache', err)));
});
```

You can debug it in the `application` tab of Chrome `DevTools`

Comment: Thanks so far, but what can i do, when i don't know the absolute `'paths/to/your/font/files'`? Is there a possibility to search in the site request only for files with the defined content-type?

Comment: It will depends on your tooling for instance if you're using `Webpack` https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not using Webpack. I'm using classic ES6-JS without any addons. Do you see another possibility?

Comment: Don't you use any build tool at all?

Comment: Until now, in this project, the answer is nope. In other projects i love to use npm.